# Where to ask language-related questions

Tags: discussion, hebrew, closed-questions

I've noticed that on the regular Mi Yodeya site, questions concerning Hebrew/Yiddish grammar, spelling, etc. that are not technically related to religious works are often closed. I understand the reason, because those questions are not "technically" related to Judaism but more to language arts. My question is, where are Hebrew grammar questions asked, then, if not on Mi Yodeya? Is there a Hebrew stack exchange or something?